# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: OpenCV library not found in SpringBoot with Gradle

Tags: java, opencv, gradle, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I added OpenCV dependency to my build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  implementation 'org.openpnp:opencv:4.5.1-1'
}
```

when running gradle build, the library is downloaded and build works fine. But when I run the code

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;



@SpringBootApplication
public class AiApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(AiApplication.class, args);
       System.out.print("Hello world");
       System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
       Mat mat = Mat.eye(3, 3, 0);
       System.out.println("OpenCV Mat:\n" + mat.dump());
   }}
```

I get an error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java451 in java.library.path:

So I located my Gradle file opencv-4.5.1-1.jar  and run

```
java -Djava.library.path=/home/pescador/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openpnp/opencv/4.5.1-1/31b0b04ae7565a746a15c930c3a246c2655da00c -jar ./build/libs/ai-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but with the same error. I guess I have to add some other -Djava.library.path. I do not want to use any IDE, my project run in terminal on Linux. So any advise how to setup eclipse or IntelliJ will not help.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched to maven.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0-0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and java

```
static{
    OpenCV.loadLocally();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
...
```